# How would I paste a long list of positive and negative numbers into powershell as one line?

Tags: powershell

I have a long list of numbers that I need added and subtracted inside powershell but when I paste the numbers in to the shell they all end up showing on new lines.
It looks like:

```
+15
-14
+2
```

I want it to look like `+15-14+2` without having to go in and format each number. How would I do this?

I've tried running this as one variable and powershell reads each line as a separate number to echo and print rather than process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you trust what is on the clipboard*, you can use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (`iex`) as follows - though note that [use of this cmdlet is generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375):

```
(Get-Clipboard) -join ' ' | Invoke-Expression
```

- [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard) streams what is on the clipboard *line by line*.
- [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) `' '` joins the resulting lines to form a single-line string, with the input lines separated with `' '` (a single space).
- `Invoke-Expression` evaluates the resulting single-line string as PowerShell code.